# Want to sort a file with random characters and numbers without using the sort function in python

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

Below is where I started to create a script to be used to take a .txt file and sort it by upper case, lower case, special characters, and numeric. I feel like I am missing something very simple. Any suggestions to push me in the right directions will be appreciated. I am using Python 3.5.1

```
#!usr/bin/python

ifname = raw_input('Enter the input file name: ')

try:
    fhand = open(ifname).read()
    print fhand

except:
    print 'File cannot be opened:', ifname


Upper = []
Lower = []
Number = []
Special = []

for x in range(len(fhand))
    if fhand[x] <= 'Z' and fhand[x] >= 'A':
        Upper = fhand[x]

print Upper
```

Returns one value and not a list

Edit the script to reflect suggestions:

```
 for x in fhand
    if x <= 'Z' and x >= 'A':
        Upper.append = (fhand[x])

print Upper
```

The results are as follows:

```
$ python file_sorting.py
Enter the input file name: Unknow.txt
 ds dfa
 877
 444, 50, 33
 #$, %%,
 7 7 7 8 5 2 3
S
DD SD
W
A 
A
T
bb
dfg

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "file_sorting.py", line 21 in <module>
  Upper.append(fhand[x])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're writing `range(0, len(some_sequence))` you're doing something wrong. Don't do that. Use an iterator. Python string objects already have methods to test for `isupper`, `isalpha`, `isnumber`, etc. So just write:

```
for x in fhand:
    if x.isupper():
        Upper.append(x)
    ...
```

Second, I'm not sure why you're avoiding python's `sort()`. If you use the `key` keyword argument you can specify how the comparison ought to be done, and this allows quickly sorting a sequence into groups.

Finally end off using itertools.groupby to group it, and you're done.

```
from itertools import groupby

fhand = open('/etc/passwd', 'r').read()
sorter = lambda x: x.isupper() and 'upper' or x.isdigit() and 'digit' or \
    x.isalnum() and 'alpha' or 'special'

for g, li in groupby(sorted(fhand, key=sorter), sorter):
    print g, list(li)
```

Edit: Thinking back to job interviews at Amazon, there might be a reason for avoiding sort, and they are fond of asking that question: What if the file is HUGE? Well, then sorting it takes O(n*log(n)), and just iterating through it is O(n). But if the file is huge, you should not be building lists out of the characters :-)

Comment: I was unaware of Python iterator. Do they have one for special characters? Your last part with itertools, is confusing. I will need to research what you are referring to.  The object is to handle any file to find patterns.

Comment: Your script works like I want it, Thanks. However, how do get all of the '/n' and whitespace in the special list?

Comment: I used a lambda to make a quick and crude sorter, but nothing prevents you from writing your own function that takes a character as argument and returns the 'class' it should be sorted under. Then you can check if the character is in [' ', '\t', '\r', '\n'] and assign it to the special list. Re groupby, all it does is go through a sorted list, and start a new group when it encounters a new key. So this groups your sorted list into smaller lists.

Comment: I really appreciate the assist. I notice in each list created it is not sorted. Any ideas how I would sort the strings in each list?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add to list. You need replace it:

```
Upper = fhand[x]
```

to

```
Upper.append(fhand[x])
```

Also, you can use like:

```
for char in fhand:
    if char <= 'Z' and char >= 'A':
        Upper.append(fhand[x])
```

Comment: And you don't need to say `for x in range(len(fhand))`.  You can just say `for x in fhand`.

Comment: JRazor - I applied your suggestions. However, I am getting a TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str.